# Code Optimize : Shifting a List of Integers in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

**Requirement** : There's an input List and an input shift no.
The first line contains two space-separated integers that denote :

- *n*, the number of integers, and
- *d*, the number of left rotations to perform.

The second line contains space-separated integers that describe *arr[]*.

**Constraints**

- 1 <= n <= 10^5
- 1 <= d <= n
- 1 <= arr[i] <= 10^6

**Sample Input**

- 5 , 4
- 1 2 3 4 5

**Sample Output**

5 1 2 3 4

I have written this code which is working correctly but getting timeout while large operation. So I need to optimize my code to successfully run all the test cases. How to achieve that.

```
public static List<Integer> rotateLeft(int d, List<Integer> arr) {

    int size = arr.size();
    while(d>0) {
        int temp = arr.get(0);
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
            if(i != size-1){
                arr.set(i,arr.get(i+1));
            } else {
                arr.set(i,temp);
            }
        }
        d--;
    }
    
    return arr;

}
```

Failing for this input :

- n = 73642
- d = 60581
- And a huge Integer List of size 73642.

Comment: I have to wonder that if you're asking how to improve or optimize working code, then perhaps this is perhaps better posted on the [Stack Exchange Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Use your own list implementation, then you can just cut it and modify some pointers. Or if there is only one test case just read in an array and then do a loop to output the correct order. You could even read in everything as a String cut and swap.

Comment: Is this actually a matter of running the operation on a background thread, so that the UI isn't frozen?

Comment: I am practicing ds and algo problems from hackerrank. This is one of the question from there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this community isn't mean to review working code.

Comment: The fastest way *by far* would be to write a wrapper `List` implementation that simply delegates all access to the original one after calculating the new offset of the desired element. No need to move any part of the content anywhere.

Comment: @JoachimSauer that would be the most efficient solution if a list was actually required. But since the task is defined by text input and output and afaik, hackerrank doesn’t judge over what the program actually does but only about producing the expected output, there are even more efficient solutions possible.

Comment: @Holger: I took the request to mean "how to implement *this method* in the most efficient way". But yes, if text output is required, then it can be done even faster and with less code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: it is unsure that this trick is efficient, that depends on the processing that follows. Because on every access the index will need to be recomputed (with a test or a modulo), and this computation could be repeated many times.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: first, this is clearly from some hackerank-style question where the further processing is almost guaranteed to be just dumping the content to stdout or some other verification. Second, even if that wasn't the case I'm still fairly confident that in most cases my approach works faster, since calculations are *significantly* faster than memory access and we're replacing duplicate (unnecessary) memory access with a very simple calculation (repeated frequently). But yes, if this was for some unspecified general case, then the actual advantages/disadvantages would have to be inspected.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: my comment relates to real life: if you rotate the vector, you will most probably... access it some day (that will cost you both index recomputation and memory access). I also disagree to say that the "simple calculation" will be faster than a memory access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using nested loops, this can be done in one loop. The final index of an element at index `i` after `n` shifts, can be calculated as `(i + n) % listLength`, this index can be used to populate a shifted list. Like this:

```
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        System.out.println(rotateLeft(4, arr));
    }
    
    public static List<Integer> rotateLeft(int d, List<Integer> arr) {
    List<Integer> rotatedList = new ArrayList<>(arr.size());
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i< arr.size(); i++) {
        int rotatedElementIndex = ((i+d) % arr.size());
        rotatedList.add(arr.get(rotatedElementIndex));
    }
    return rotatedList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup mate, i got that %  logic. Thanks again ! I just modified these 2 lines to avoid iterating the List everytime. `int size = arr.size();      for(i=0; i< size; i++)`

Comment: The `%` operator is costly. Prefer two separate loops, on the first `d` and on the next `n-d` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Never liked hackerrank puzzles. What does "and a huge Integer array" mean? May we create a new list or we need to modify existing one? If we ought to modify existing one why our method is not void?

If we may create new list the optimal solution would be creating new Integer[] array and call System.arraycopy() twice.

In case of inline modifications the solution is:

```java
    public static List<Integer> rotateLeft(int d, List<Integer> arr) {
        int i = 0, first = arr.get(0);
        int n = arr.size();
        while (true) {
            int source = (i + d) % n;
            if (source == 0) {
                arr.set(i, first);
                break;
            }
            arr.set(i, arr.get(source));
            i = source;
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For an in-place solution:

- reverse the subarrays `arr[0, d)` and `arr[d, n)` in-place. This is done by swapping the elements in symmetric pairs.
- reverse the whole array.

E.g., `abcdefghijk`, `d=4`

```
abcd|efghijk -> dcba|kjihgfe -> efghijk|abcd
```